# Как сделать слайд, чтобы при клике все картинки смещались вправо-влево?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, css-animation

Как реализовать таким образом, чтобы при нажатии на L все картинки смещались влево, а при нажатии на R наоборот?

```js
const hamburger_menu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
        const container = document.querySelector(".container");
        const bottom = document.querySelector(".bottom");

        hamburger_menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
            container.classList.toggle("active");
            bottom.classList.toggle("show");
        });

        const arrow_right = document.querySelector(".right");
        const main = document.querySelector(".main");
        const shadow_one = document.querySelector(".one");
        const shadow_two = document.querySelector(".two");
        arrow_right.addEventListener("click", () => {
            shadow_one.style.transform = "perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5)";
            shadow_one.style.left = "350px";
            shadow_one.style.zIndex = "3";

            shadow_two.style.transform = "perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5)";
            shadow_two.style.left = "100px";
            shadow_two.style.zIndex = "2";

            main.style.transform = "perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5)";
            main.style.left = "-25px";
            main.style.zIndex = "1";
        });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
        }

        img{
            position: absolute;
            width: 600px;
            height: auto;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .container{
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #485461;
            background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #485461 0%, #28313b 74%);
            overflow-x: hidden;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }

        .navbar{
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .hamburger-menu{
            height: 4rem;
            width: 2rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 150px;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        .bar{
            width: 2rem;
            height: 1.5px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background-color: #eee;
            transition: 0.5s;
            position: relative;
        }

        .bar:before,
        .bar:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: #eee;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .bar:before {
            transform: translateY(-9px);
        }

        .bar:after {
            transform: translateY(9px);
        }

        .main{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 5;
            overflow: hidden;
            transform-origin: left;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        header{
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: grey;
        }

        .overlay{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .container.active .bar{
            transform: rotate(360deg);
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .container.active .bar:before{
            transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
        }

        .container.active .bar:after{
            transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
        }

        .container.active .main{
            animation: main-animation 0.5s ease;
            left: 350px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
        }

        @keyframes main-animation{
            from{
                transform: translate(0);
            }

            to{
                transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
            }
        }

        .links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 20%;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            z-index: 2;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        ul{
            list-style: none;
        }

        .links a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fcec0c;
            padding: 0.7rem 0;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(10px);
            animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease;
        }

        .links a:hover{
            color: #978d01;
        }

        .container.active .links a{
            animation: appear 0.5s forwards ease var(--i);
        }

        @keyframes appear{
            from{
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translateY(10px);
            }
            to{
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translateY(0px);
            }
        }

        @keyframes hide{
            from{
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translateY(0px);
            }
            to{
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translateY(10px);
            }
        }

        .shadow{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-origin: left;
            transition: 0.5s;
            background-color: white;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .shadow.one{
            z-index: -1;
      background-color: red; 
     }
            

        .shadow.two{
            z-index: -2;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .container.active .shadow.one{
            animation: shadow-one 0.6s ease-out;
            left: 100px;
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5);
        }

        @keyframes shadow-one{
            0%{
                transform: translate(0);
            }

            5%{
                transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
            }

            100%{
                transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5);
            }
        }

        .container.active .shadow.two{
            animation: shadow-two 0.6s ease-out;
            left: -25px;
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5);
        }

        @keyframes shadow-two{
            0%{
                transform: translate(0);
            }

            20%{
                transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
            }

            100%{
                transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5);
            }
        }

        .container.active .main:hover + .shadow.one{
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(230px) scale(0.5);
        }

        .container.active .main:hover{
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(340px) scale(0.5);
        }

        .bottom{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            display: none;
        }

        .show{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            top: -125px;
        }

        .arrow{
            font-size: 64px;
            margin: 0 200px;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 10;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fcec0c;
        }

        .arrow:hover .far{
            color: #978d01;
        }
```

```html
<img src="Image/header.png" alt="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="hamburger-menu">
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="main">
                <header>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </header>
            </div>

            <div class="shadow one"></div>
            <div class="shadow two"></div>

            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="arrow left">L</div>
                <div class="arrow right">R</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="links">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" style="--i: 0.05s;">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" style="--i: 0.1s;">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" style="--i: 0.15s;">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" style="--i: 0.2s;">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если прям не хочется использовать библиотеки слайдов, то можно реализовать таким образом (Добавил побольше комментариев для понимания):

```js
    const hamburger_menu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const bottom = document.querySelector(".bottom");

    hamburger_menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
        container.classList.toggle("active");
        bottom.classList.toggle("show");
    });

    let arrow_right = document.querySelector(".right"); // Правая кнопка
    let arrow_left = document.querySelector(".left"); // Левая кнопка
    const main = document.querySelector(".main");
    const shadow_one = document.querySelector(".one");
    const shadow_two = document.querySelector(".two");
    let moveR = [[shadow_one,shadow_two,main],[shadow_two,main,shadow_one],[main,shadow_one,shadow_two]]; // Массив блоков для удобства смены

    arrow_right.addEventListener("click", () => { // для правой кнопки
        let trig = +arrow_right.dataset.val+1; // Получаем триггер из кнопки
        if(trig >= moveR.length){ // Если больше чем количество в массиве, то ставим 0
            trig = 0;
        }
        move(trig); // Выполняем функцию с движением направо
        arrow_right.dataset.val=trig; // проставляем новое знаечние дата параметра в кнопку
    });

    arrow_left.addEventListener("click", () => { // для левой кнопки
        let trig = +arrow_right.dataset.val-1; // Получаем триггер из той же самой кнопки
        if(trig < 0){ // Если меньше нуля, то ставим количество элементво массива -1, так как ключи начинаются с 0.
            trig = moveR.length-1;
        }
        move(trig); // Выполняем функцию с движением
        arrow_right.dataset.val=trig; // проставляем новое знаечние дата параметра в кнопку
    });

    function move(trig) { // Выносим отдельно в универсальную функцю для удобства
        let z=moveR[trig]; // Берём нужный массив
        z[0].style.transform = "perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5)";
        z[0].style.left = "350px";
        z[0].style.zIndex = "3";

        z[1].style.transform = "perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5)";
        z[1].style.left = "100px";
        z[1].style.zIndex = "2";

        z[2].style.transform = "perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5)";
        z[2].style.left = "-25px";
        z[2].style.zIndex = "1";
    }
```

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
    *{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    }

    img{
        position: absolute;
        width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .container{
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #485461;
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #485461 0%, #28313b 74%);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .navbar{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .hamburger-menu{
        height: 4rem;
        width: 2rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 150px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .bar{
        width: 2rem;
        height: 1.5px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: #eee;
        transition: 0.5s;
        position: relative;
    }

    .bar:before,
    .bar:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        background-color: #eee;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .bar:before {
        transform: translateY(-9px);
    }

    .bar:after {
        transform: translateY(9px);
    }

    .main{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 5;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform-origin: left;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    header{
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .overlay{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .container.active .bar{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .container.active .bar:before{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
    }

    .container.active .bar:after{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .container.active .main{
        animation: main-animation 0.5s ease;
        left: 350px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
    }

    @keyframes main-animation{
        from{
            transform: translate(0);
        }

        to{
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
        }
    }

    .links{
        position: absolute;
        width: 20%;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 2;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    .links a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fcec0c;
        padding: 0.7rem 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(10px);
        animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease;
    }

    .links a:hover{
        color: #978d01;
    }

    .container.active .links a{
        animation: appear 0.5s forwards ease var(--i);
    }

    @keyframes appear{
        from{
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(10px);
        }
        to{
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }

    @keyframes hide{
        from{
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
        to{
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(10px);
        }
    }

    .shadow{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-origin: left;
        transition: 0.5s;
        background-color: white;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .shadow.one{
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: red;
    }


    .shadow.two{
        z-index: -2;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .container.active .shadow.one{
        animation: shadow-one 0.6s ease-out;
        left: 100px;
        transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5);
    }

    @keyframes shadow-one{
        0%{
            transform: translate(0);
        }

        5%{
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
        }

        100%{
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5);
        }
    }

    .container.active .shadow.two{
        animation: shadow-two 0.6s ease-out;
        left: -25px;
        transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5);
    }

    @keyframes shadow-two{
        0%{
            transform: translate(0);
        }

        20%{
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
        }

        100%{
            transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5);
        }
    }

    .container.active .main:hover + .shadow.one{
        transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(230px) scale(0.5);
    }

    .container.active .main:hover{
        transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(340px) scale(0.5);
    }

    .bottom{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        display: none;
    }

    .show{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        top: -125px;
    }

    .arrow{
        font-size: 64px;
        margin: 0 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 10;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: #fcec0c;
    }

    .arrow:hover .far{
        color: #978d01;
    }
```

```html
<img src="" alt="">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="main">
            <header>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="shadow one"></div>
        <div class="shadow two"></div>

        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="arrow left" data-val="-1">L</div>
            <div class="arrow right" data-val="-1">R</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" style="--i: 0.05s;">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" style="--i: 0.1s;">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" style="--i: 0.15s;">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" style="--i: 0.2s;">Testimonials</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: функционал есть, но при закрытье первый должен увеличится до первоначальных размеров, но в вашем коде есть недостаток

Comment: @ПростаMiha Если в коде есть недостатки, попробуйте их устранить самостоятельно. Автор ответа взялся вам помочь с решением, но он не обязан решать задачу за вас в полном объёме.